# Getting student grade values for grade objects

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'm trying to use valence to get all students' grades for a given grade object. But, I'm only finding actions for getting the current user's grade values. Given an instructor, is there a way to get everyone's grade values for a grade object? Or, do I need to get the class list, and individually get each student's grade for a grade object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Currently, you must first retrieve a list of the users in the class and then iterate over them to retrieve grade values for a specific grade object (line item in the grade book). This is a gap in the Valence Learning Framework API that others have also identified, and has been called out for implementation in a future release; precise timing of when it will be released isn't yet available, though.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I'm proceeding with getting a class list and iterating over them to get the grades.

Comment: This would be very helpful.  Any update on the release timeline?

Comment: Not at this time, no.